Is it true that if two $m$-degree polynomials intersect on $m^2$ points, then some $C_3$ that intersects on $m^2-1$ points intersect on the $m^2$th?
Is it generally true that if two $m$-degree algebraic curves $C_1$ and $C_2$ intersect at $m^2$ specific points, a $m$-degree curve $C_3$ that passes through $m^2-1$ points must pass through the $m^2$th point as well?
Or is this only true for certain polynomials?
My motivation to finding an answer to this question is that I want to simplify the Cayley-Bacharach theorem.
Rather than looking up the proof of the Cayley-Bacharach theorem, perhaps look at the proof of something else?

You say polynomials, but don't you mean algebraic curves?

I guess I do mean algebraic curves.

Take a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1988659/cayley-bacharach-for-higher-degree-curves?rq=1

It's generally not true that three algebraic curves of degree $m$ $C_1$, $C_2$, and $C_3$ that intersect on $m^2 - 1$ points will intersect on all the same $m^2$ points.
However, cubics are a special case.
Cubics have 9 degrees of freedom, which means 9 points define a cubic. Unlike quadrics, where they have 5 degrees of freedom. Degrees of freedom is pretty much defined by the number of terms that describe the overall family of curves (by the degree of the curve) minus 1. Quadrics have 6 terms, so 5 degrees of freedom. Cubics have 10 terms, so 9 degrees of freedom.
The space of all cubics thus could have been expressed as 10 linear equations, but because scalar multiples represent same cubics, we introduce 1 linear condition, and thus are left with 9 linear equations.
For each condition that you impose on the space of cubics, you reduce the degree of freedom by 1, and thus the total number of equations in a system drops by 1.
If you are to enforce 8 linear conditions on a family of curves, you'd be left with a system of 2 linear equations.
A system of 2 linear equations effectively describes a pencil of two cubics.
Now, by Bézout's theorem, two cubics will intersect in exactly 9 points.
This is important to know, because unlike other curves, such as quadrics—which have 5 degrees of freedom but will have two quadrics intersect on at most 4 points—cubics have 9 degrees of freedom, and intersect on exactly 9 points.
This is why cubics are special. Not only do they have 9 degrees of freedom, but they also have it so that two cubics intersect on 9 points, unlike other curves. So if you know the 8 out of the 9 points that a cubic passes through, then it will essentially pass through the 9th point. This is because two cubics in a linear combination will share the same 9 points, and the third curve will also share the same 9points.
But this is not always true for all curves.
Quadrics have 5 degrees of freedom. A pencil of quadrics will have 4 specific points that are 0. But, a quadric that is known to pass through 3 specific points is described not by a pencil, but by a linear combination of 3 quadrics. So the system can perhaps have two quadrics that share the same zero-points of the third quadric, but a third is needed. Strictly speaking, we may have imposed that the two quadrics in the linear combination to share the same vanishing points, but since we did not specify that the third quadric in the linear combination to share the same vanishing points as the two others, then there is no guarantee that the linear combination of just two quadrics will span the family of all curves that pass through 4 specific points.
